# Preloader div not fades out again - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, fadeout, preloader

I have a preloader div over a simple html page. When the page is loaded it fades out. 
When I reload images it not fades out again, how can I 'reset' the preloader?

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<div id="preloader"></div>
    <ul>
        <li id="k1" class="topimg"></li>                
        <li id="k2" class="topimg"></li>                
        <li id="k3" class="topimg"></li>                
    </ul>
<div id="reload"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {

function loader(){ 
    $("#preloader").css({'display':'block'});               
    $(window).load(function() {
        $("#preloader").fadeOut();
    });
}; //loader

loader();

/* I reload the images on click (image names are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6....) */

$('#reload').click(function(){      
            loader(); /// <<< preloader div not fades out again

            // change images
            i1 += 3;                    
            i2 += 3;                    
            i3 += 3;                    
            $('#k1').css({'background':'url("images/' + i1 + '.jpg")'});
            $('#k2').css({'background':'url("images/' + i2 + '.jpg")'});
            $('#k3').css({'background':'url("images/' + i3 + '.jpg")'});
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt test this since you have not included enough code, but my guess is when you press your reload button this only effects the div that contains your images?

This function also calls the loader() function which tells preloader to be set to block but then your call to hide it `$(window).load(function() { });` cant be run because your page has already been loaded.

---

**update**

I am not sure if you can run a .load() check on a div since your just slotting images into it when the button is pressed, someone who knows more about jquery could answer this for you. But what I've done below is just call your display on `#preloader` directly and then added a loaded class to it. The if statement just checks to see if it has this class and if it does it fades it out again.

```
$('#reload').click(function(){      
    $("#preloader").css({'display':'block'});
    $("#preloader").addClass( "loaded" );

    $('#k1').css({'background':'url("http://placehold.it/300")'});

    if ($("#preloader").hasClass( "loaded" ) ) {
           $("#preloader").fadeOut();
    }
});
```

---

**Update 2**

I was curious to see what the .load() can be called on and it can be done on `<iframe>` and `<img>` tags if this works for you, you can point to the img src and check to see if it has loaded then fade out the preloader. See example [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bosc/e86umgyb/) and code below

```
$('#reload').click(function(){      
    $("#preloader").css({'display':'block'});

    $('#mainImg').attr('src', 'http://placehold.it/300');     

    $('#mainImg').load(function(){
        $("#preloader").fadeOut();
    });

});
```

Comment: Yes, when you press the button it loads new images for the list items background. How can I select these images for the .load() function?

Comment: updated the answer with some jquery that might work for you, like i said in it not sure if you can check if a div is loaded.

Comment: Thank you that you were thinking on my problem! I think the correct way should be if I use some ajax call for the images (when reload) and in this way I can make a preloader for the incoming data or something like that. I'm a beginner in this but I will see about. Thank you very much again!

Comment: Still learning the ins and outs of jquery myself and was curious to see what can be done with the .load() seems img tags can be checked with the .load() so did a small update above if proves helpful.